Referencing Apex Class Members from LWC with imperative controller call
I'm trying to figure out how to reference in LWC class members of an Apex class that is returned by a controller, not sObjects and their fields.  Every example I have found is the same getAccounts or getContacts example which returns sObjects.
Here's a segment of my Apex ---
    public class Week {
        @AuraEnabled public Datetime weekDateTime; // Could be any time between start and end of week.
        @AuraEnabled public String weekName;
        @AuraEnabled public list<String>dayNameList;
        @AuraEnabled public list<String>dateNameList;
        @AuraEnabled public list<TimeRow>timeRowList;
    }
...
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static Week getDataForWeek(Id eventid) {
        Week myWeek = new Week();
        myWeek.weekName = 'Something.';
...
        return myWeek;
    }

The Apex call in the LWC js...
    fetchData() {
        try {  
            this.weekData = getDataForWeek( { eventid : this.eventid} );
            alert (this.weekData);  // this says it's a promise.
            this.error = undefined;
        } catch (error) {
            this.weekData = undefined;
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

And a reference in the LWC html...
    <template lwc:if={weekData}>
        Got It. {weekData.weekName} 
    </template>

After "Got it." nothing appears.  I feel like I'm missing some knowledge of how to address the members of the Apex class.  The members do have @AuraEnabled.  Darn but all the examples have only sObjects and if I set that getContacts/getAccounts example again, I'm going to scream.  Life isn't all about sObjects.

I did find a solution and that is to use a different syntax in the .js for the call.
    fetchData() {
        getDataForWeek( { eventid : this.eventid} )
        .then((result) => {
            this.weekData = result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('In connected call back error....');
            this.error = error;
            console.log('Error is', this.error); 
        });
    }

I worked from an example in this thread -- How to call imperative apex method from connectedCallback() in LWC
It took me a long time to find it as the first 20 examples I found where the same getAccounts/getContacts example.
Don't know if there's a better answer so feel free to post any other solutions or tips.

Read about Promises and async/await e.g. here https://javascript.info/async. Generally async/await is the way to go as it reads more like synchronous code.
